# PHP Facebook Curl Post Logged in User(curl)

Tags: php, curl

i have this script to login to a Facebook account:

```
<?php

$login_email = 'email';
$login_pass = 'pass';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://m.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'charset_test=€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є&email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Charset: utf-8','Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,bn-bd;q=0.3','Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd ());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd ());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "user_agent");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://m.facebook.com");
$fbMain = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

$url = 'http://m.facebook.com/home.php?refid=18';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$demo_mac=curl_exec($ch);
echo $demo_mac;
?>
```

It works great. But now i need to post a message on wall with curl. How can i do it ? (Yes i know it is not allowed by Facebook TOS).Thank for reply.